# Pass a variable to javascript function in html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, thymeleaf

I have a table in html, filled via a many items. The row's code is this:

```
<tr th:each="item : ${srcResults}">
    <td th:text="${item.something}"style="vertical-align:middle;" />...
    <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
        <label class="btn btn-primary" title="Details" onclick="submitDetails(${item});">
             <i class="fa fa-info" />
        </label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and the javascript function that's called is:

```
submitDetails = function(item) {
    console.log('I have been called');
};
```

But It does not work and chrome's console says

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
>    referring to the label tag.

I have to use the item object but I do not know how to pass it to the js function

Comment: what is the output of `${item}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this

```
onclick="submitDetails('"+${item}+"');"
```

Comment: I've used this `onclick="submitDetails('${item}');"` and it worked. Thanks